# Translating 2 subtitles (TV drama 03:31 and 03:39)

Tags: translation

below find dialog of ２ druglords and the brother of one of them 江东和江南兄弟 and  林力华 at the start of part 8 of TV drama 国家形象,
http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTA2MDgwNDQw.html

03:31 includes 拿手 （adjective，adept; expert; good at），

０３：３９ has 有一手 （
很有一手 highly skilled 手 measure word for abilities）

context and gestures might suggest something like indicated translations. Dialog suggests play on word
手.

国家形象：第8集 
两名毒枭，江东与林力华和江冻的弟弟江南之间的对话：

０２：１０：江东：我江东是什么人早晚你会知道的

０２：１４：现在我们是把买卖做成

０２：１７：靠你来操作你做不成 对吧

０２：３４：提到诚意 我对你有诚意

０２：３８：我想看到你的诚意

０２：４１：想看到你真正想加入红动集团的诚意

０２：４５：林力华：我们是合作

０２：４６：江东：是 是 是

０２：４７：合作也罢  假如也罢 不过是个字眼

０２：５２：我想看到你的诚意

０３：０２：林力华：大哥 我再让一步

０３：０５：你定地点我定时间

０３：１０：江东：好（江东同林力华握手）

０３：１２：林力华：我先走了（江东拍林力华的背）

０３：２２：江东：江南

０３：２５：打击一个人的自尊心让人变的软弱

０３：２９：有什么方法最有效

０３：３１：江南：这我拿手 哥（am I supposed to be an expert on that, is this in my line of expertise，am I supposed to know ?)

０３：３３: 按照道上的规矩把他脚筋挑了

０３：３９：江东：不对  你还有一手 (wrong, do you have another way)

（江东开始大笑并打了江南脸上微微一巴掌，看起来这就让江南有些困惑，他挠了挠自己上唇上的地方）

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: question: how to translate 03:31 and 03:39 correctly

Comment: ０２：４７ 有打印错误，应该是＂合作也罢 加入也罢 不过是个字眼＂。好像OP在使用拼音输入法编辑器时是打空格键了的而不是打需要的２数字键。02:47 has a typo, should have 加入 instead of 假如, apparently due to hitting space key instead of needed numeral 2 key （while using the usual IME editor）。

Comment: 关于在先的评论请注意，名词"键＂和＂动词＂按＂搭配而名词＂字母、数字＂和动词＂打＂搭配就是说可以说＂按（下）空格键＂和＂打数字＇２＇＂可是＂打空格键、２数字键＂不对。Please note collocation of 键 with 按 and 字母、数字 with 打。

Comment: Since you were trying to make this full script as a discussion instead of asking specific question. I would like to point out you shall not use "打印错误" if you want to say I made a typo since you are not a printer or program that printing some output. You would say `打错了` or `写错了`.

Comment: 多谢在先的评论，也许值得指出的是用＂打字错误＂也可以。typing error 打字错误

Comment: You could say, `多谢你之前的评论，值得注意的是，这里也可以用“打字错误”` But you should really say `字打错了` instead of `打字错误`. You grammar seems fine to me, but it seems a bit awkward in a couple of spot since you are trying to translate literally from English.

Comment: see iciba for "typing error"

Comment: iciba translates most of phrase literally word by word so it might look awkward when you put these translated words together. Actually, most of the translator nowadays did not do a good job on translate phrases. What I was suggesting is the expression that most of native-Mandarin speaker would say.

Answer (score 2):

拿手，
means good at， skillful.

literally means i am very familiar with doing so (just like using my hand).

不对，你还有一手。
You are better than that.

Alternative, 江东 is expecting 江南 think outside the box. 江南 didn't realize that and show confusing expression.